# Is it possible to break axis labels into 2 lines in base graphics?

Tags: graphics, r

I am trying to have the x-axis labels to be split into two lines. I would also like the labels to be rotated 45 degrees. How can I do this?

What I have so far:

```
N <- 10
dnow <- data.frame(x=1:N, y=runif(N), labels=paste("This is observation ",1:N))
with(dnow, plot(x,y, xaxt="n", xlab=""))
atn <- seq(1,N,3)
axis(1, at=atn, labels=labels[atn])
```

Comment: What do you mean 2 lines?  Do you mean you want "This is\n observation ..."?

Comment: @chis_dubois That's the first part of the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's one possibility with the `ggplot2` package.

```
N <- 10
labs <- factor(1:N,labels=paste("This is \n observation",1:N))
dnow <- data.frame(x=1:N, y=runif(N), labels=labs)
qplot(labels,y,data=dnow) + 
      opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=-45,hjust=0))
```

[image]

I'm looking forward to seeing the base package examples, too!

Comment: @chris - I would like to accept your question (all the cool kids use ggplot2 these days). But, could you fix the x-axis before hand (ggplot orders character vectors alphabetically, so you have to convert it to a factor.) Thanks!

Comment: Good suggestion.  I switched it to be a factor, but the right hand side is still being cut off.  I'll try and fix that.

Comment: this also works for data labels - if you drop a \n into them, it will break lines!

Answer (score 4):

This is what I cooked up (before my `ggplot2` days) using base graphics:

```
## data
N <- 10
dnow <- data.frame(x=1:N, y=runif(N), labels=paste("This is \nobservation ",1:N))
## make margins wide
par(mfrow=c(1,1), mar=c(10,10,6,4))
## plot without axix labels or ticks
with(dnow, plot(x,y, xaxt="n", xlab=""))
## the positions we ant to plot
atn <- seq(1,N,3)
## the label for these positions
lab <- dnow$labels[atn]
## plot the axis, but do not plot labels
axis(1, at=atn, labels=FALSE)
## plot labels
text(atn, ## x position
     par("usr")[3]-.05, ## position of the low axis
     srt=45, ## angle
     labels=lab, ##labels
     xpd=TRUE, ## allows plotting outside the region 
     pos=2)
## par("usr")[3]
```

Comment: I think this is also a important contribution.  With `ggplot2` probably this is not required.  But it is good to have too.  Also a better and elegant solution with `grid` is given in the R Graphics book by Paul Murrel.